# Django - New fonts?

Tags: python, django, fonts

How do I install new fonts with Django? There is no mention of this in the documentations.

I have my fonts installed in the static folder as such fonts/abc.ttf

For instance, in a template if this was a CSS I would link it as such:

```
    <link href="{% static 'fonts/abc.ttf' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

except this is not CSS, and I haven't found any resources on how to to do this.

Do I include the link in the CSS file like so?

```
  @font-face {
  font-family: 'abc';
  src: url({% static 'fonts/abc.ttf' %});
  src: local({% static 'fonts/abc.ttf' %})
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How about : `src : url("../fonts/sbc.ttf")` If  your `fonts` directory is in the previous folder as this css file ?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

For the directory structure like so,

```
-- static
 |--fonts
 | |--abc.ttf
 |
 |--css
   |-- main.css
```

In the `main.css`, you should add.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'abc';
  src: local('Abc'),
       url('../static/fonts/abc.ttf') format("truetype");
}
```

You **can't use `{% static 'filename' %}` inside a css file**, since it will not be rendered by the django templating engine.

Also, if you want you can add the following in the `<head>` section of  `base.html`, and it will render a fully qualified path for static assets:

```
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'abc';
    src: local('Abc'),
         url('{% static 'fonts/abc.ttf' %} format("truetype")');
  }
</style>
```

*Edit*: Fixed the use of `local` and also removed the preference around location of style tag in html.

Comment: The local part was tripping me up for some reason. Ended up just including the font-family and src:url and it worked.

Comment: @DGDD you should use a font generator with all the required fonts for cross browser and put the appropriate css for them.   http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator is recommended.

Comment: @DGDD I fixed the local parameter.  It shouldnt inlcude static, and the ttf should include the format

Comment: Can you explain why it's not advisable? I can think of lots of reasons why I might want to deliver a fully constructed page with the CSS in the <head> tag.

Comment: _`url('../static/fonts/abc.ttf')`_ Does `../static/fonts/` need to be exposed as a route somewhere eg _urls.py_ ?

Comment: It gave me a double 'static' as in ../static/static/fonts/abc.ttf. Ended up removing static and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I am using this option to avoid absolute path and/or css in html template:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'HKGrotesk';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    src: local('HKGrotesk'), url('/static/fonts/hk-grotesk/HKGrotesk-SemiBoldLegacy.otf') format('opentype');
}
```