# Import font in Django template

Tags: python, html, css, django, fonts

I want to import a font in django template

I use this code

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'sans-serif';
    src: url('{% static 'fonts/20db.otf' %}');
}
```

[This is where my static file is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0VHz.png)

Comment: Use this if u importing on css file `src: url('fonts/20db.otf');`

Comment: here is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346045/django-new-fonts