# Django, CSS3, and font-face: how to load local font files?

Tags: css, django

So I have a Django app `<my-app>` and I would like to load some local font files into the base template `<my-app>/templates/<my-app>/base.html`.

For example, under `<my-app>/static/<my-app>/fonts/Lato/` I have several `.ttf` files:

- Lato-Black.ttf
- Lato-BlackItalic.ttf
- Lato-Bold.ttf
- etc

and in `<my-app>/static/<my-app>/css/fonts.css` I have:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src:
  local('Lato-Black') url('../fonts/Lato/Lato-Black.ttf') format('truetype'),
  local('Lato-BlackItalic') url('../fonts/Lato/Lato-BlackItalic.ttf') format('truetype'),
  local('Lato-Bold') url('../fonts/Lato/Lato-Bold.ttf') format('truetype'),
  local('Lato-BoldItalic') url('../fonts/Lato/Lato-BoldItalic.ttf') format('truetype'),
  local('Lato-Hairline') url('../fonts/Lato/Lato-Hairline.ttf') format('truetype'),
  local('Lato-HairlineItalic') url('../fonts/Lato/Lato-HairlineItalic.ttf') format('truetype'),
  local('Lato-Italic') url('../fonts/Lato/Lato-Italic.ttf') format('truetype'),
  local('Lato-Light') url('../fonts/Lato/Lato-Light.ttf') format('truetype'),
  local('Lato-LightItalic') url('../fonts/Lato/Lato-LightItalic.ttf') format('truetype'),
  local('Lato-Regular') url('../fonts/Lato/Lato-Regular.ttf') format('truetype')
  ;

}
```

Accordingly in `base.html`:

```
  {% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '<my-app>/css/fonts.css' %}" />
```

This does not load the fonts so that I can use them as if I used Google's api:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
```

So how do I fix my CSS?

Comment: can you give project file structure , + Put this in HTML file {% load static %}, + Put this in django settings STATIC_URL = '/static/' and STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static") and if you put ttf file inside static/fonts you can use  url('{% static 'fonts/abc.ttf' %}');

Comment: and check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346045/django-new-fonts

Comment: @Vaibhav my apologies, I excluded the load static (already in `base.html`) because I thought it was implied Ill update my question. The linked question does not resolve my problem

Comment: try to put @font-face inside <script> tag inside template(base.html) and test if its working and do use url('{% static 'fonts/abc.ttf' %}')

Comment: Can you provide the output of the browser console after loading the `base.html`?

Comment: @abybaddi009 no console output :)

Comment: @Vaibhav that doesnt work

Comment: try with  lcoal('{% static 'fonts/abc.ttf' %}'); instead of url(%static '//'%) inside @font-face

Comment: @Vaibhav sorry, doesnt work either

Answer (score 0):

I know that it is late to respond, but as nobody answered the question, and this question appears in search, we need to answer the question in order to be not asked by another user.

So to solve this, put all of those font files in the static folder, and import them in css file like below:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src:
  local('Lato-Black') url('/static/fonts/Lato/Lato-Black.ttf') format('truetype'),

}
```