# How to use a downloaded font in a django project instead of google fonts api

Tags: html, css, django, fonts

I cant find a solution to my problem anywhere, so i am hoping for some help.
I am new to programming and to django as well.
I followed the following [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/series/beginners-guide/1.11/) until the start of part 4.

So far so good. Now i've found a new font online that i would like to use, instead of the google font the tutorial is using, for the django "logo" in the topbar (its called Crimson Foam).

The problem is, that i have no clue how to use it in my base.html file and what to do with my css files (I've seen that you apparently need to use those).
My static files are organised like so:

```
-- static
 |--fonts
 | |--crimson_foam.ttf
 |
 |--css
   |-- app2.css
   |-- bootstrap files
```

I've tried it like that:

templates/base.html

```
{% load static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Django Boards{% endblock %}</title>
    <link href="{% static 'fonts/crimson_foam.ttf' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/app2.css' %}">
  </head>
Rest of the html file
```

I tried 2 different .css file versions:

static/css/app2.css

Version 1:

```
title {
    color:#FAB4FF;
    font-family: "Crimson foam";      #didnt know what to put there
}
```

Version 2:

```
.navbar_brand {
    font-family: "Crimson foam", regular;
}
```

To be honest i am overwhelmed by how much there is to know about django. I know that there are similar threads but they arent talking about the html base file and i am not advanced enough to see where to change things.

Thanks to everybody in advance for reading this long text!

Comment: check out this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346045/django-new-fonts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For everybody, that finds his way to my question, i found an answer:

My solution uses a css method called @font-face.

To achieve the wanted result, we have to add the following code to our css file:

css/app2.css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Any name you want to give your font for further use";
    src: url("either an absolute path from your homedirectory or a relative path");
}

# in my Case the code looked like this:

@font-face {
    font-family: "Crimson Foam";
    src: url("../fonts/crimson_foam.ttf);
}
```

That way you add your font with the name "Crimson Foam" to your pool of usable fonts. You can put many @font-face methods in one .css file.

To use the just declared fontname, you can do one of two things:

1. assign it to an html specific tag:

```
html-tag.your_method_name {
    font-family: "One of the fonts you assigned with @font-face", style (like regular or cursive);
    font-size: A percantage (like 150%) or pixel like "36px";
}

# In my case, that looked like this:

h1.crimson_method {
    font-family: Crimson Foam, regular;
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

2. You can also create a font-method without specifying a tag, which could look like this:

```
.method_name {
    font-family: "";
    font-size: "";
}
```

After you did that, you also have to mention your method name in your html file, in the class="something" part.
That could look like this:

```
{% load static %}<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title class="crimson_method">{% block title %}Django Boards{% endblock %}</title>
  </head>
Rest of the html file
```

The links that i used in the html section of my questions, are used to refer to a website, where i had google fonts from. There is also a method to implement google fonts, but for that topic there are plenty of good tutorials like [this one](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started) on the web.