# Downloaded font face in django not working

Tags: css, django, fonts

I am trying to implement the downloaded font face either in the template or either in the css file both are not working. I have downloaded the fonts and store in the structure like this

```
Static folder
    css (sub folder inside the static folder)
      --style.css file inside the css folder
    fonts (sub folder inside the static folder)
      --ZillaSlab-Regular.ttf  file inside the fonts folder
```

this is how implement the font face in django inside the css file

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif;
    src: local('ZillaSlab'),
         url("../fonts/ZillaSlab-Regular.ttf") format('truetype');       
  }
body{
    font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif !important;
}
```

I have also tried to implement via static block in the template but it is also not working

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif;
    src: local('ZillaSlab'),
         url("{% static '/fonts/ZillaSlab-Regular.ttf' %}") format('truetype');
         
  }
body{
    font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif !important;
}
```

Comment: Did you clear browser history and try again? Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346045/django-new-fonts

Comment: yes i have also done this