# xhtml2pdf heroku can't load font

Tags: css, django, heroku, fonts, xhtml2pdf

I'm creating a PDF based on xhtml2pdf (Django). In my localhost I need to provide absolute path for font **'D:\user\folder1\folder2\project\static\fonts\DejaVuSansMono.ttf'** because reference of **{% static 'fonts/DejaVuSansMono.ttf' %}** doesn't work. My font isn't loading. If i provide absolute path, it is working fine. But it isn't working when I publish my app on Heroku. I don't know how to do. I know that the xhtml2pdf has reference only on xhtmlpdf catalog (please correct me if I'm wrong).

What should I do that the font will be working on localhost and Heroku too?
I've tried to do something like that but it isn't working as well.

`base_url = "{0}://{1}{2}".format(request.scheme, request.get_host(), request.path)`

My app in heroku return only **/static/fonts/DejaVuSansMono.ttf**

Comment: you cant directly include .ttf file using static tag in template. You have to use font face in css. Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/21348380/11282077

Comment: I have same problem here have you solved it?[](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68298921/heroku-cant-connect-pdf-fonts)https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68298921/heroku-cant-connect-pdf-fonts